# A cubic Bezier patch and its control cage inaccurate rendering

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, glut, opengl-3

I am trying to port an example from chapter 8 of the Superbible OpenGL 7th ed. and the control cage lines are not going from point to point as in the example gif or the image on page 375 of the book.  Instead its rendering the lines to just a single point.  I have provided it below.  Thank you.

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

Actual output I am receiving:

[image: actual output]

Support files: [cubicbezier_support.zip](https://github.com/ohlogic/PythonOpenGLSuperBible7Glut/blob/master/chapt08/cubicbezier_support.zip)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time
import ctypes

fullscreen = True
sys.path.append("./shared")

#from sbmloader import SBMObject    # location of sbm file format loader
from ktxloader import KTXObject    # location of ktx file format loader
from textoverlay import OVERLAY_
from shader import shader_load, link_from_shaders

from sbmath import m3dDegToRad, m3dRadToDeg, m3dTranslateMatrix44, m3dRotationMatrix44, m3dMultiply, m3dOrtho, m3dPerspective, rotation_matrix, translate, m3dScaleMatrix44, \
    scale, m3dLookAt, normalize

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()

import numpy as np
from math import cos, sin
import glm
identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,1]

#myobject = SBMObject()
ktxobject = KTXObject()
overlay = OVERLAY_()

tess_program = GLuint(0)
draw_cp_program = GLuint(0)
patch_vao = GLuint(0)
patch_buffer = GLuint(0)
cage_indices = GLuint(0)

patch_data = [glm.vec3() for _ in range(16)] 

show_points=False
show_cage=False
wireframe=False
paused=False

class uniforms:
    class patch:
        mv_matrix=0
        proj_matrix=0
        mvp=0

    class control_point:
        draw_color=0
        mvp=0

uniform = uniforms()

def load_shaders():
    global uniform
    global tess_program
    global draw_cp_program

    if (tess_program):
        glDeleteProgram(tess_program)

    shaders = [GLuint(0) for _ in range(4)]

    shaders[0] = shader_load("cubicbezier.vs.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    shaders[1] = shader_load("cubicbezier.tcs.glsl", GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER)
    shaders[2] = shader_load("cubicbezier.tes.glsl", GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER)
    shaders[3] = shader_load("cubicbezier.fs.glsl", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    tess_program = link_from_shaders(shaders, 4, True)

    uniform.patch.mv_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(tess_program, "mv_matrix")
    uniform.patch.proj_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(tess_program, "proj_matrix")
    uniform.patch.mvp = glGetUniformLocation(tess_program, "mvp")

    if (draw_cp_program):
        glDeleteProgram(draw_cp_program)

    shaders[0] = shader_load("draw-control-points.vs.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    shaders[1] = shader_load("draw-control-points.fs.glsl", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    draw_cp_program = link_from_shaders(shaders, 2, True)

    uniform.control_point.draw_color = glGetUniformLocation(draw_cp_program, "draw_color")
    uniform.control_point.mvp = glGetUniformLocation(draw_cp_program, "mvp")

class Scene:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        global patch_vao
        global patch_buffer
        global cage_indices

        load_shaders()

        glGenVertexArrays(1, patch_vao)
        glBindVertexArray(patch_vao)

        glGenBuffers(1, patch_buffer)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, patch_buffer)

        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)*3*16, None, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW)
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

        indices = [
            0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3,
            4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7,
            8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11,
            12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15,

            0, 4, 4, 8, 8, 12,
            1, 5, 5, 9, 9, 13,
            2, 6, 6, 10, 10, 14,
            3, 7, 7, 11, 11, 15
        ]

        ar = np.array(indices, dtype='int')

        glGenBuffers(1, cage_indices)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cage_indices)
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)*len(indices), ar, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        overlay.init(80, 50)
        overlay.clear()
        overlay.drawText("W: Toggle wireframe", 0, 0)
        overlay.drawText("C: Toggle control cage", 0, 1)
        overlay.drawText("X: Toggle control points", 0, 2)
        overlay.drawText("P: Pause", 0, 3)

    def display(self):

        currentTime = time.time()

        gray = [ 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0 ]
        one = 1.0

        last_time = 0.0
        total_time = 0.0

        if (not paused):
            total_time += (currentTime - last_time)
        last_time = currentTime

        t = total_time

        patch_initializer = [
            -1.0,  -1.0,  0.0,
            -0.33, -1.0,  0.0,
             0.33, -1.0,  0.0,
             1.0,  -1.0,  0.0,

            -1.0,  -0.33, 0.0,
            -0.33, -0.33, 0.0,
             0.33, -0.33, 0.0,
             1.0,  -0.33, 0.0,

            -1.0,   0.33, 0.0,
            -0.33,  0.33, 0.0,
             0.33,  0.33, 0.0,
             1.0,   0.33, 0.0,

            -1.0,   1.0,  0.0,
            -0.33,  1.0,  0.0,
             0.33,  1.0,  0.0,
             1.0,   1.0,  0.0,
        ]

        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, gray)
        glClearBufferfv(GL_DEPTH, 0, one)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        p = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_float)*3*16, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT)

        ppp = ((ctypes.c_float * 3) * 16).from_address(p) 

        for i in range(0, 16):

            fi = float(i) / 16.0

            ppp[i][0] = patch_initializer[i*3]
            ppp[i][1] = patch_initializer[(i*3)+1]

            ppp[i][2] = sin(t * (0.2 + fi * 0.3))

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)

        glBindVertexArray(patch_vao)

        glUseProgram(tess_program)

        proj_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        proj_matrix = m3dPerspective(m3dDegToRad(50.0), float(self.width) / float(self.height), 1.0, 1000.0)

        T = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        m3dTranslateMatrix44(T, 0.0, 0.0, -4.0)

        RX = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        m3dRotationMatrix44(RX, t * m3dDegToRad(10.0), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        RY = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        m3dRotationMatrix44(RY, t * m3dDegToRad(17.0), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

        mv_matrix = (GLfloat * 16)(*identityMatrix)
        mv_matrix = m3dMultiply(T, m3dMultiply(RX, RY))

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform.patch.mv_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, mv_matrix)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform.patch.proj_matrix, 1, GL_FALSE, proj_matrix)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform.patch.mvp, 1, GL_FALSE, m3dMultiply(proj_matrix , mv_matrix))

        if (wireframe):
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)
        else:
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)

        glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 16)
        glDrawArrays(GL_PATCHES, 0, 16)

        glUseProgram(draw_cp_program)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform.control_point.mvp, 1, GL_FALSE, m3dMultiply(proj_matrix , mv_matrix))

        if (show_points):
            glPointSize(9.0)
            glUniform4fv(uniform.control_point.draw_color, 1, [0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0])
            glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 16)

        if (show_cage):
            glUniform4fv(uniform.control_point.draw_color, 1, [0.7, 0.9, 0.2, 1.0])
            glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 48, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None)

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL)
        overlay.draw()

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen
        global show_cage
        global show_points
        global wireframe
        global paused

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle
            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True
        elif key == b'c' or key == b'C':
            show_cage = not show_cage
        elif key == b'x' or key == b'X':
            show_points = not show_points
        elif key == b'w' or key == b'W':
            wireframe = not wireframe
        elif key == b'p' or key == b'P':
            paused = not paused
        elif key == b'r' or key == b'R':
            load_shaders()

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):
        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)
    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Cubic Bezier Patch')
    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
    fullscreen = False
    #glutFullScreen()
    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)
    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)
    scene.init()
    glutMainLoop()
```

ported from: [cubicbezier.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/cubicbezier/cubicbezier.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the element array is specified, then the the type of the indices is `types.c_int` respectively `'int'`:

> ```
> ar = np.array(indices, dtype='int')
> glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cage_indices)
> glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
>    ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)*len(indices), ar, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
> ```

But, when the lines are drawn by [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml), then the specified type is `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`.

> ```
> glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 48, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, None)
> ```

The 3rd parameter in `glDrawElements` specifies the data type of the indices in the array. If the data in the array are of type *uint32*  then the enumerator constant has to be `GL_UNSIGNED_INT`. If type of the indices is *uint16*, then the type has enumerator constant has to be `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`.

Change the type pf the array form `ctypes.c_int` to [`ctypes.c_ushort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) respectively from `'int'` to [`np.uint16`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html), to solve the issue:

```py
ar = np.array(indices, dtype=np.uint16)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_ushort)*len(indices), ar, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

Note, if the type in the array is `types.c_int` then each index is stored to 4 bytes. But if the specified type is `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`, then every 2nd byte is expected to be an index. This causes that every second index is 0.

Comment: Excellent explanation, very clear and insightful.  Perfect answer.  I learned a lot about those data types.  Thank you immensely and many times over!